# Trying to find a simple way to copy specific files to a new directory using C#

Tags: c#, file, foreach, copy

I'm trying to copy all files that were modified in the last 24 hours to a new directory. I have a method that determines which files to copy, but I'm having trouble actually getting them copied. Here's what I have:

```
ModifiedFiles newFiles = new ModifiedFiles();
targetPath = @"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Home Office";
foreach (var file in newFiles.modified()) 
    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetPath, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
```

`Path.GetFileName()` wants a string instead of a `FileInfo` object (file), but if I add `.ToString()` to it, `File.Copy()` gets mad that its "file" isn't a string too.

I'm new to C# (if you couldn't tell!) and have two main questions here:

1. How can I make this work?
2. Why do I need to create the full path+filename of the destination file at all? It seems weird that I can't just specify which files to move and tell them where to go, without worrying about explicitly stating what they should be called when they get there. Unless I'm reading it wrong? I've been poking around on the MSDN website and Stack Overflow and most people seem to agree this is the way to do it, though.

Comment: Instead of using Path.GetFileName(file), can't you just use file.Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `File.Copy` method accepts full file paths for the source and destination, so if you're using `FileInfo`, you'll want to use the `Name` and `FullName` properties.

```
File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(targetPath, file.Name), true);
```

Also, as a general rule, you don't want to just call `ToString()` on an object and hope it returns something meaningful. A class *may* override `ToString()` and return some value, or it may not and the value you get back is simply the class type. Check the documentation first.